# How to get different value for id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I trying to get different value from id kode for my script. My script only get the first value.

```
<table id="myTable" style="margin-left: 50px;">
              <tr class="header">
                <th style="width:30%;"></th>
                <th style="width:30%;"></th>
                <th style="width:30%;"></th>
              </tr>
              <?php 
                foreach ($barang as $br) 
                { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $br->nama_barang ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="kode<?php echo $br->kode_barang ?>" value="<?php echo $br->kode_barang ?>" readonly="true"></td>
                    <td><button style="color: blue;" onclick="getkode<?php echo $br->kode_barang ?>()">get</button></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php }
              ?>
            </table>
```

The script

```
function getkode() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("kode");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Comment: In `jquery` I would do this `$(input[id^="kode"]')` or a begins with selector.  Your id is not `kode` its `id="kode<?php echo $br->kode_barang ?>"` whatever that is.

Comment: what are you trying to do in long term? Right now it looks like a very complicated way to get what you already have (the $br->kode_barang). You could simply pass that into `onclick="getkode(<?php echo $br->kode_barang; ?>)"`

Comment: @jeff - it looks like they are copping it to the clipboard.  On click of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what I would do

Change these:

```
 <td><button style="color: blue;" onclick="getkode<?php echo $br->kode_barang ?>()">get</button></td>
```

To this:

```
 <td><button style="color: blue;" onclick="getkode('<?php echo $br->kode_barang ?>')">get</button></td>
```

So you pass `$br->kode_barang` as an argument of the function on click.  Then:

```
function getkode(kode_barang) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("kode"+kode_barang);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

PS. I wrote this jQuery clipboard plugin a while ago, your welcome to use it if you want

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/jqClipboard.js

if I remember my own code right you would just do something like

```
$('body').jqClipboard('copy', html);
```

It uses a dynamically created textarea to copy the content.  So it can copy any HTML to the clipboard even just strings.